# What is confusing about upcase-region?

Tags: functions, capitalization

Using `upcase-region` gives the message about it being disabled because new users find it confusing; but it seems very straightforward—replace every character with its upper-case version, if there is one.  Am I missing something in what the function does?  Or is there a whole discussion recorded about this somewhere?

Comment: My guess is that new users are not familiar with "the region", especially the inactive region. If I hit `C-x C-u` (`upcase-region`) by accident, the affect is unpredictable to me since I have no idea where the current mark is, even though I have been an Emacs user for 2 or 3 years.

Comment: [The ChangeLog entry](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/ChangeLog.3#n10639) corresponding to [the change](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/diff/src/casefiddle.c?id=d427b66a664c0e1ffc818dfa5b87b45b4857d2ae) doesn't give any reason.

Comment: I agree with @xuchunyang - the function itself isn't confusing, but if you called it by accident, you'd see part of your buffer upcased for no apparent reason. Even worse, if the region is mostly off-screen, you wouldn't even know that the text had been changed until later. *That* would be confusing.

Comment: @npostavs, wow that is a long time ago.  I am guessing that nobody can remember now exactly what happened.  Or only a few people can, and none of them would be on here.  Shame.